# Run my custom task in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio & using Gradle as build tool. In my build.gradle, I defined a custom task:

```
def myTask {
  ...
}
```

I would like to run the task right after the *class.dex* file is generated. I tried:

```
myTask.dependsOn(dex)
```

Gradle gives error: **Could not find property 'dex'**

Then, I tried:

```
myTask.dependsOn(dexDebug)
```

Gradle gives error: **Could not find property 'dexDebug'**

My questions are:

1. Why I got this error? I see at least there is a task named `dexDebug` in task list. Why I cannot depends my task on it?
2. How to define my task to run right after class.dex file is generated then?

(I am using Gradle Android Plugin v1.0.0, Gradle v2.2.1)

Comment: Note that making your task depend on dexDebug won't cause it to be run after each time dexDebug runs -- it insures that if you invoke your task explicitly, dexDebug will be run first.

Comment: I know that, actually I have also build.dependsOn(myTask) which ensures they all run

Comment: @ScottBarta, why you think my question is duplicated with the one you linked? We are asking different things, in my question I said I can see the task dexDebug listed in gradle while the question in your link is trying to run task which is not listed. Please check my question carefully & remove the "mark as duplicated". You blocked me from starting a bounty .

Comment: Your question is slightly different, but not in any essential details compared to the linked question -- that questioner is trying to set up a dependency on an Android Gradle task that doesn't exist during the phase of execution where the dependency was being set up, and the answer is to put it in a `gradle.projectsEvaluated` block.